# error: pasting "." and "red" does not give a valid preprocessing token

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm implementing The X macro, but I have a problem with a simple macro expansion. This macro (see below) is used into several macros usage examples, by including in [`this`](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html) article.
 The compiler gives an error message, but I can see valid C code by using `-E` flag with the GCC compiler.

The macro X-list is defined as the following:

```
#define LIST \
  X(red, "red") \
  X(blue, "blue") \
  X(yellow, "yellow")
```

And then:

```
#define X(a, b) foo.##a = -1;
  LIST;
#undef X
```

But the gcc given the following errors messages:

```
lixo.c:42:1: error: pasting "." and "red" does not give a valid preprocessing token
lixo.c:42:1: error: pasting "." and "blue" does not give a valid preprocessing token
lixo.c:42:1: error: pasting "." and "yellow" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

Like I said, I can seen valid C code by using `-E` switch on gcc:

```
lixo.c:42:1: error: pasting "." and "red" does not give a valid preprocessing token
lixo.c:42:1: error: pasting "." and "blue" does not give a valid preprocessing token
lixo.c:42:1: error: pasting "." and "yellow" does not give a valid preprocessing token
  foo.red = -1; foo.blue = -1; foo.yellow = -1;;
```

What's a valid preprocessing token? Can someone explain this?

(before you say "why not just an either initialize or `memset()`?" it's not my real code.)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`.` separates tokens and so you can't use `##` as `.red` is not a valid token. You would only use `##` if you were concatenating two tokens into a single one.

This works:

```
#define X(a, b) foo.a = -1;
```

> What's a valid proprocessing token? Can someone explain this?

It is what gets parsed/lexed. `foo.bar` would be parsed as 3 tokens (two identifiers and an operator): `foo   .   bar` If you use `##` you would get only 2 tokens (one identifier and one invalid token): `foo   .bar`

Comment: So is the section "Pasting tokens" in [this article](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html) is simply wrong?

Comment: @QuentinUK Didn't know it would work on Visual Studio. Maybe some of them isn't stricty C standard.

Comment: @QuentinUK There's only one definition of what's right and wrong (literally, that's the purpose of a standard), but sometimes a programmer is not the only part of the toolchain who meets the criteria of being wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

Notably, the GCC [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) says your example should compile, albeit with a warning:

> two tokens that don’t together form a valid token cannot be pasted together. For example, you cannot concatenate x with + in either order. If you try, the preprocessor issues a warning and emits the two tokens.

However, as you have noticed, invalid tokens in macros result in an [error](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) since GCC 4.3 (circa 2008).