# How to create macro with different behavior depending on parameters number?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

I want to create one macro that will work differently in case when it HAS parameters or NOT.

For example: there are two different implementation of printing error:

```
// 1. Print message = check code
#define PRINT_IF(wasError) \
    do { if (wasError) printf(#wasError); } while(false)

// 2. Throws an exception with formatted message
#define PRINT_TEXT_IF(wasError, format, ...) \
    do { if (wasError) printf(format, ##__VA_ARGS__); } while(false)
```

And I'd like to have one macro for both cases.

What I've tried is create a global macro that checks if it has parameter or not, based on approach from [How to count the number of arguments passed to a function that accepts a variable number of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421681/how-to-count-the-number-of-arguments-passed-to-a-function-that-accepts-a-variabl).

```
#define RANDOM_GUID "5c300a82-2fe8-4bd3-ad12-ef13fa7b4a82"
#define FIRST_ARG(a1, ...) a1
#define HAS_ARGS(...) FIRST_ARG(##__VA_ARGS__, RANDOM_GUID)

#define GLOBAL_PRINT_IF(wasError, ...)             \
    do {                                           \ 
      if (wasError) {                              \
        if (HAS_ARGS(##__VA_ARGS__)==RANDOM_GUID ) \
          PRINT_IF(wasError);                      \
        else                                       \
          PRINT_TEXT_IF(wasError, __VA_ARGS__);    \
      }                                            \
    } while(false)
```

I assume that because `FIRST_ARG` always return first argument, it will return `RANDOM_GUID` if `##__VA_ARGS__` are empty.

But this code doesn't compile with  [error: pasting "." and "red" does not give a valid preprocessing token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216423/error-pasting-and-red-does-not-give-a-valid-preprocessing-token).
I've tried to play with `##` before `__VA_ARGS__`, but it fails with `expected primary-expression before ‘==’ token`
in line

```
if (HAS_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__)==RANDOM_GUID )
```

So, what am I doing wrong? How to deal with it properly?

Comment: Wouldn't variadic templates be a lot better suited for this since you're using C++? Example a bit like what you want at the bottom: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Comment: @HWalters I change it from throwing exception to print. Now it fits to ```c``` tag?

Comment: Start by looking how to get the number of argument in a variadic macro [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124339/c-preprocessor-va-args-number-of-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

1. Start by looking how to **get the number of argument** in a variadic
   macro [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124339/c-preprocessor-va-args-number-of-arguments)
2. Then when you know how to get the number of argument, you can easily
   **check if this number is 0**.

And this snippet returns the number of argument event if this is 0:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINT(...)  (printf("%d\n", sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(int)))

int main(void)
{
    PRINT();
    PRINT(1,1);
    PRINT(1,1,1,1);
    return 0;
}
```

so easily, this second snippet does the job

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINT(...)  (((sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(int))==0)?printf("do A\n"):printf("do B\n"))

int main(void)
{
    PRINT();
    PRINT(1,1);
    PRINT(1,1,1,1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's actually very hard to have "get the number of arguments" return 0 as you can't actually call a macro with 0 arguments -- you can only call with an empty argument which will generally show up as one (empty) argument.  With a lot of work, you can write a macro that returns 0 if called with a single empty argument and the number of arguments otherwise, but the OP doesn't actually need it -- he just needs to know the difference between 1 and 2 or more arguments.